Is it possible to remove base path from @RequestMapping for one specific method?
For example a have this controller class
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class A {
    @GetMapping("get")
    public String someMethod() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/secondGet")
    public String someMethod2() {
        return "Hello there!";
    }
}

I want "someMethod2" to ignore base path "/api/", I want to make it possible to ivoke this method by "/secondGet" path, not "/api/secondGet". Is it possible? Or I need to make another controller class for this?

You have to configure a second controller.

No, it's not possible the only way is to create an additional controller or provide separate URLs for your endpoints like this.
@RestController
public class RestContoller {

    @GetMapping("/api/get")
    public String someMethod() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/secondGet")
    public String someMethod2() {
        return "Hello there!";
    }
}


You can use
 @GetMapping(value={"", "/", "api"})

to bind multiple paths.
